# Android things to olimax board

Tags: android-things

How to connect Android things to olimax board.

I want to create the Iot application, For that i need to connect to Android things application to Olimax board.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have control over the code of the Olimax board?

Answer (score 0):

Very good documentation:
https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart

```
manager.getUartDeviceList();
...
11-20 09:00:15.417  1610  1626 I MainActivity: Device found: /dev/bus/usb/001/009 id: 1009
11-20 09:00:15.417  1610  1626 I MainActivity: product name: STM32 Virtual ComPort
11-20 09:00:15.419  1610  1626 I MainActivity: List of available devices: [MINIUART, UART0, USB1-1.5:1.0]
```

Connected USB Cable between STM32F105 board and Raspberry pi board. Because the Raspberry pi board recognises the virtual ComPort from the STM32F105 board you can access the uartdevice directly.
I can create a UartDevice mDevice with (deviceList.get(mydevice) = "USB1-1.5:1.0"):

```
mDevice = manager.openUartDevice(deviceList.get(mydevice));
```

In the end i can use something like this to write some data:

```
public void writeUartData(UartDevice uart, String data) throws IOException {
    int count = uart.write(data.getBytes(), data.length());
    Log.d(TAG, "Wrote " + count + " bytes to peripheral");
}
```